# How to make a dynamic array Fibonacci series java program?

Tags: java, arrays, fibonacci

I am in 8th grade. I am taking a 12th grade java course. I just started and my home work is to make a Fibonacci series dynamic array program. I don't know where to go. It is online so I can't ask a teacher or something.

How do you make a Fibonacci sequence using a dynamic array in Java?

This was an example of a dynamic array I got:

[image]

I don't see how you can make the Fibonacci series out of it! Here is the Fibonacci series example I got.

[image]

Comment: Please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the documentation in the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help).  In particular, you should read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what sorts of questions are [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here at SO.

Comment: Best way to make a Fibonacci is using recursive function. Google it.

Comment: Just in case you are wondering why the downvotes, its because this is asking the community to do your homework for you. What have you tried doing?

Comment: I don't know what to try! The lesson was 2 examples. One of the Fibonacci series, and another of the dynamic arrays. It didn't even teach me anything. I can't find anything on the web about how to make a dynamic variable program.

Comment: A dynamic array is one that resizes when you are about to overflow it. A Fibonacci sequence goes something like 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 etc. to an nth. Start by figuring how to get a fibonacci sequence to the nth digit and then work on putting it into an array that resizes. And actually, now that I look at the examples they just basically give you the code for both. So you don't really have to even write anything.

Comment: so how do I turn that into a Fibonacci series program? I don't understand why you wouldn't want to use a reg array.

Comment: @JaydenOrr "Please don't mark this down because last time I couldn't ask a question for 2 days!" That's a sign that you're getting near the [question ban](http://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) for asking lots of questions that aren't appropriate for Stack Overflow. Begging not to be downvoted won't help; just improve your questions and ask better ones in future and you'll have no trouble. Be sure to go through the pages that azurefrog linked to help you learn what SO is about.

Comment: @JaydenOrr regular arrays are bounded to what you instantiate them to -- this is tell ing the operating system you want to allocate a specific amount of memory for your application.  When you've use up the memory you've requested you need to request more.  Memory doesn't grow on trees.

Comment: @Aurora0001  this is my first question, EVER!

Comment: @JaydenOrr how did you get downvoted previously then if this is your first question? Did you create another account or just delete previous bad questions?

Comment: @Aurora0001 This is another account

Comment: Off topic! REALLY!! I just need help! Why is there soooo many rules at this forum?

Comment: @JaydenOrr probably best not to do that; see [this page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) - the section "Can I simply create a new account?" shows how you could have all of your accounts banned or an IP ban. Here's why your post was voted as off-topic: uses images rather than including code; doesn't contain a minimal example and it seems to be just asking for the full answer code rather than solving a problem you have with your code.

Comment: @Aurora0001 That is what my teacher gave me. The two examples. Thats it! No lesson. His assignment was to make the Fibonacci series a dynamic array. I just started programming in general a month ago and if someone would just show me how to do it, it would clear up a lot of confusion.

Comment: @Aurora0001 I changed my ip

Comment: @Aurora0001  besides, why is there so many rules! No other forum is like this!!

Comment: @Aurora0001 The day I join, after my first question, it says you can't ask anymore questions. So I make a new account. I ask you guys to cut me some slack, and guess what! You down vote me! My parent know nothing about computers! I am basically alone with a pc trying to do a online java course that doesn't teach anything! I just want some help!

Comment: @JaydenOrr no-one expects you to know everything (or else there'd be no point having a Q&A site) but you are expected to format your question in a specific way (see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)). The important thing to realise that SO isn't just a programming forum - it's a collection of useful questions and answers, so questions that won't be useful to others will be removed. If your current course is not useful, I would try looking for another online course.

Comment: @Aurora0001 I am doing it through michigan state virtual university. I can't quit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine the two examples, as such:

Take the `DynamicArrayOfInt` class, and add the `main` method of the `Fibonacci` class.

Insert a new statement at the beginning of the `main` method instantiating a `DynamicArrayOfInt` object, as such:

```
DynamicArrayOfInt arr = new DynamicArrayOfInt();
```

Replace every instance of `numbers[x]` with `arr.get(x)`, and instances of `numbers[x] = y` with `arr.put(x, y)`.

Remove the leftover statements dealing with the numbers array. This will essentially make use of the DynamicArrayOfInt object. A sample output would look like this:

```
iplante$ java DynamicArrayOfInt
Size of dynamic array increased to: 2
Fibonacci series:

0
1
Size of dynamic array increased to: 4
1
2
Size of dynamic array increased to: 8
3
5
8
13
Size of dynamic array increased to: 16
21
34
55
89
144
233
377
610
Size of dynamic array increased to: 32
987
1597
2584
4181
iplante$
```

Comment: public class Fibonacci {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numbers;
        numbers = new int[20];
        numbers[0] = 1;
        numbers[1] = 1;
        System.out.println("\nFibonacci series:\n");
        System.out.println(numbers[0]);
        System.out.println(numbers[1]);
        for (int i = 2; i < 20; i++) {
            numbers[i] = numbers[i-2]+numbers[i-1];
            System.out.println(numbers[i]);
        }
    }
}